# Como compruebo si se ha cliqueado fuera de el JList?

Tags: java

Tengo añadido un JList en mi marco de esta manera:

```
//JList que se vuelve visible al presionar en Game
ListaJuego = new JList<>();
ListaJuego.setLayout(null);
ListaJuego.setBounds(0, 20, 150, 230);
ListaJuego.setBackground(new Color(200, 255, 200));
ListaJuego.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new Color(20, 100, 20)));
add(ListaJuego);
```

Quiero que al cliquear fuera de este, se ponga `ListaJuego.setVisible(false);`, el problema es que el `Jlist` esta encima de muchos `JPanels`, y para no añadir un `MouseListener` a cada `JPanel` quisiera saber si hay algún método lo opuesto a `MousePressed()`, o si hay otra manera?

> **Edit**: se que se puede ponerle a la interfaz un `MouseListener` asi:
> `public class Clase implements MouseListener{...}` pero obligatorio me toca crear un `MouseEntered()`, un `MouseExited()` y 3 mas si no estoy mal, y no me gusta. Tampoco se si existe una manera de que no cree todos esos metodos.

Comment: Y si añades un clickListener pero a la ventana entera, en vez de a cada componente?? Luego solo tendrás que comprobar si ha hecho el click en el jlist o en otro sitio...

Comment: Se me olvido comentar eso en la pregunta, espera la edito

Comment: @Benito, añadí un MouseListener desde el constructor y me funciono igual, xd, gracias de igual

Comment: También si no quieres implementar todos los métodos de MouseListener puedes extender de MouseAdapter (o directamente crear una instancia) y usar solo los métodos que necesites.

Comment: @JFrame mmm ya, mi error era que yo usaba implements en vez de extends, gracias por el dato